# Scroll RecyclerView with current Complete visible item height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagersnaphelper

I have RecyclerView that contains user post , post height is not fixed , I have attached `PagerSnapHelper` to this RecyclerView .

How can I make scrolling distance of this RecyclerView with current complete visible item in RecyclerView .

```
binding.videoTrendsRecycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);           
binding.videoTrendsRecycle.setMediaObjects(videosResponse.getVideosResponseArrayList());
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.findTargetSnapPosition(mLayoutManager, 0, 1000);
binding.videoTrendsRecycle.setOnFlingListener(null);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.videoTrendsRecycle);
VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter adapter = new VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter(videosResponse.getVideosResponseArrayList(), initGlide(context), context);
```

Comment: Are you want to first of all scroll item and then main recycler view?

Comment: @HardikTalaviya I want to to scroll recycleview but I want scroll to be with current item height distance , hope that is clear ?

Comment: Means are you want item also scroll with recyclerview?

Comment: @HardikTalaviya yes

Comment: If you are scroll inside item So first of item scroll as per height?